# How can I use UpSet plot for expression/RNA-seq data

Tags: r, upsetr

I have a `data.frame` of `27 000 x 17` and I want to feed it into `UpSetR` program, but getting the error:

> Error in start_col:end_col : argument of length 0

My `data.frame` looks like that:

[image]

And the `upSetR` code that I am using:

```
upset(df, nsets = 4, number.angles = 30, point.size = 3.5, line.size = 2, 
mainbar.y.label = "Gene Intersections", sets.x.label = "Genes Per Group", 
text.scale = c(1.3, 1.3, 1, 1, 2, 0.75))
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I found here a similar issue:

https://plus.google.com/109635504520741246387/posts/Etujrp6sU1Q

They say that the input should be binary. But then, how can I calculate this binary matrix from the `rlog`-data? I am not sure...

Comment: UpSet plots are in many ways similar to Venn diagrams, in that the represent some sort of metric for group overlap. What I expect you want to do is get the number of DE genes in various comparisons and put those numbers into an UpSet plot.

Comment: upsetR takes as input a data.table in the long format. I found [this example/code](http://crazyhottommy.blogspot.de/2016/01/upset-plot-for-overlapping-chip-seq.html) very helpful when I first started using upsetR.

Comment: I need to get the binary matrix to be able to feed it into the UpSetR. Right now I have a matrix where rows are genes and columns are groups. Somehow for each gene I need to set a threshold value to convert it to binary ‘expressed/not expressed’ probably. Groups are vectors of numbers, so I need to find their intersection somehow. I do not know which software or R package do that: I would not want to do it manually.

Comment: I am pretty confused but the problem is rather definite: I need to represent groups, their similarity, as an UpSet plot.

Comment: I think, it would be good to rephrase your question to match your ultimate goal something like "How can I use UpSet plot for expression/RNA-seq?". Say what is you sample and why you want to do the UpSet plot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate a list of gene ID vectors to feed into `upset`. In the example below, I am selecting observations (genes) which have an level above the median level. You could also choose only genes above the 3rd quartile, etc. You then need to convert these from a list of character vectors to a presence/absence matrix. UpSetR has a `fromList` function that does just this.

In future, be more specific about what you want to achieve and supply example data for people to work with.

```r
library("UpSetR")

tmp <- mtcars

tmp$car <- rownames(mtcars)
list <- lapply(colnames(mtcars), function(x) {
  tmp[tmp[[x]] > median(tmp[[x]]), "car"]
})
names(list) <- colnames(mtcars)

upset(fromList(list))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [script](https://github.com/sdmiller93/Public_Scripts/blob/master/up_down_flat.R) to create the binary data frame with my differential expression data. If it is of any help to anyone: